# How can I click dropdown?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, dropdown

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVQMC.png)

code

```
driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'ellipsis1')][1]")).click()
```

error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
```

if bug code change to

```
driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'ellipsis1')][1]")).click()
```

error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[contains(@class,'ellipsis1')][1]"}
```

FULL CODE

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import pyperclip
import re



id = 'YOUR_ID' # 네이버 아이디
ps = 'YOUR_PASS' # 네이버 비밀번호

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\stockauto\selenium\chromedriver.exe') #드라이브 크롬으로 설정
driver.get('https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login') # 네이버 로그인 창으로 이동
time.sleep(1) # 1초 대기


tag_id = driver.find_element_by_name('id') # id 입력할 곳을 tag_id 변수로 저장
tag_pw = driver.find_element_by_name('pw') # pw 입력할 곳을 tag_pw 변수로 저장
tag_id.clear() # tag_pw 창에 있는 정보를 지움
time.sleep(1) # 1초 대기

tag_id.click() # tag_id창 클릭
pyperclip.copy(str(id)) # id 클립보드에 복사
tag_id.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v') # 붙여넣기
time.sleep(1) # 1초 대기

# pw 입력
tag_pw.click() # tag_pw창 클릭
pyperclip.copy(str(ps)) # pw 클립보드에 복사
tag_pw.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v') # 붙여넣기
time.sleep(1) # 1초 대기
pyperclip.copy('') # 클립보드 초기화

# 로그인 버튼을 클릭합니다
driver.find_element_by_id('log.login').click() # 로그인 버튼 클릭
time.sleep(2) # 2초 대기

driver.get('https://admin.blog.naver.com/'+str(id)) # 검색어, 최신순으로 검색
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # 5초 암묵적 대기
print("코드 시작")
driver.find_element_by_id("buddylist_config_anchor").click()
print("1")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'ellipsis1')][1]")).click()
time.sleep(1)
```

I'm a beginner who just started coding.
I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Full-Xpath?

And you have to check one more thing. Sometimes Naver block the access when they detect macro.